# How to get the rightmost four bits from a byte

Tags: arduino-uno

I have a byte that I am looking to break into 2 nibbles. The leftmost nibble I can get easily via shifting right 4 times. However, I can't figure out how to get the rightmost nibble. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just mask it with an AND operator:

```
val = var & 0xF;
```